# Running a remote event receivers in elevated privileges

Tags: development, remote-event-receiver, runwithelevatedprivileges

I am currently migrating our server side event receivers to be remote event receivers. Now, one thing I can not find a way of doing it is how I can run part of my remote event receiver code in elevated privileges?

For example, inside my current server side ER, I have a method to create a subsite, and users who cause the server-side ER to run do not have permission to create subsites, so for this method I wrap it with this code:

```
private void yourFunction()
{
      SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
      SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

      SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
```

But I can not find a equivalent method to run part of the remote event receiver in elevated privilege? Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In On-Premise, using the code below:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourserver/");
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin user", "password", "domain");
```

In SharePoint Online, using the code below:

```
var password = "password";
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password){securePassword.AppendChar(c);}
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com")
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("User Name", securePassword);
```

**Articles below for your reference**:

[Elevated privileges in SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt210897.aspx)

[Elevate Permissions for your SharePoint CSOM code](https://newoinc.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/elevate-your-csom-permissions/)

[App-only and elevated privileges in the SharePoint add-in model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/app-only-elevated-privileges-sharepoint-add-in)